# Name cannot be null or empty. asp.net identity mvc 5 + EntityFreamwork

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

Has anyone had a problem with this. He throws me the error: Name can not be null or empty. But in the table do not have the attribute called "Name". I want to customize Asp.Net Identity.

Controller

```
  public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Home/
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        var userStore = new UserStore<User,Identity_2Context.MyRole,long,Identity_2Context.MyUserLogin,Identity_2Context.MyUserRole,Identity_2Context.MyClaim>(new Identity_2Context());
        var manager = new UserManager<User,long>(userStore);

        var user = new User()
        {
            UserName = "TehnoMac",Email = "TehnoMac@tehcno.com",IsApproved = true,IsLockedOut = false,
            CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,LastActivityDate = DateTime.Now,LastLoginDate = DateTime.Now,FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount = 0,
            FailedPasswordAttemptCount = 0
        };

        var result = await manager.CreateAsync(user, "test123test");

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var authenticationManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
            var userIdentity = manager.Create(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Text = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault();
        }

        return View();
    }
}
```

IdentityModel
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
    }

```
public class MyClaim:IdentityUserClaim<long>
{
}

public class MyRole:IdentityRole<long,MyUserRole>
{
}

public class MyUserRole:IdentityUserRole<long>
{
}
public class MyUserLogin:IdentityUserLogin<long>
{
}
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser,MyRole,long,MyUserLogin,MyUserRole,MyClaim>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: you must declare a property `Name(string)` in your customized identity.

Comment: public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; } already there

Comment: please show us your code; model, controller, view.

Comment: Up is my HomeController and IdntityModel.

Comment: Right, now please, tell us excactly, what you do, which error occurs and where.

Comment: I want to add a new user in the database (for testing). Everything went well, but the line var result = await manager.CreateAsync (user, "test123test"); doing validation for "Name", but I do not have that attribute. I tried to add it, but again the same problem. Error that occurs is: "Name can not be null or empty." Sorry for eng. :(

Comment: Is the following line correct. `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser...>` or should it read `IdentityDbContext<User....>`

Answer (score 11):

Make sure you have specified a username. I got the same error and after setting the `UserName` property, the error went away.

Comment: This helped me with the RemoveFromRoleAsync. I was mocking the UserStore and was not setting the UserName property. Kept complaining that Name could not be empty, but I was clearly setting the name property of the Role.

Answer (score 3):

Solved (for me at least) By REMOVING the UserName property from the customized identity (its in the GitHub ASPNetIdentitySample project which is where I guess people are getting it from). Its hiding the UserName property in IdentityUser

Comment: For me this was the answer

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify a UserName for identities even if you don`t use it. For example you need to log in with email and password than you can set UserName with email variable.

[passing email variable to UserName property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuPSs.png)

Why we need to do that ? Because we need a UserName in IdentityUser constructor.
[IdentityUser constructor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1DMA.png)